# How to get all the values of checkboxes into a controller

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, checkbox

I need to get a list of checkboxes from my jsp page into my spring-mvc controller. The problem is I need to know if these checkboxes where checked or not. To make things worse, I need to put them all into a list of objects. Do you guys have any idea how to do it?

**Edited: I am grabbing them by a submit form method**

In my jsp page, it look like this:

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" method="GET" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/${path }" id="productForm" commandName="product">
<c:forEach var="color" items="${product.colors}" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">${color.colorCode}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">Price <input type="text" value="${color.colorPriceUs}" name="color.colorPriceUs" id="color.colorPriceUs"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="checkbox" name="color.hidePrice" id="color.hidePrice">Do not show price</div>
    </div>
  <hr style="border-color: black">
  </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

As you can see here, i need to put the value of the chexbox into a list of `color` object when I pass this to my spring-mvc controller. *I also need to know if its value is checked or not.*

**Should I do this using jquery - ajax? Or should I just check it on the controller itself?**

Hope you can help out guys. Thanks!

Comment: Are you grabbing them on a submit method? AJAX?

Comment: @tymeJV Thanks for the question. I am grabbing them on a submit method

Comment: Then I would just check inside the controller itself - I assume this is inside a form and all gets sent back on submit?

Comment: @tymeJV If it is within the controller, I would just like to ask how I would be getting the values of these checkboxes?